# Status bar sized incorrectly with a contained UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

I make a `UINavigationController` a child of another view controller through *containment*. Everything works fine, except for a strange issue that occurs when launching the app with the **in-call status bar** turned ON and then switching it back OFF after the app UI is on the screen. There appears a strange black gap in place of the status bar.

Consider the self-contained example app below:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)opt
{
  // Content
  UILabel * aLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 200, 40)];
  aLbl.text = @"In-call status bar issue";

  UIViewController * aContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  aContent.title = @"Title";
  aContent.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
  [aContent.view addSubview:aLbl];

  UINavigationController * aNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
    initWithRootViewController:aContent];

  // Parentmost view controller containing the navigation view controller
  UIViewController * aParent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  [aParent.view addSubview:aNav.view];
  [aParent addChildViewController:aNav];
  [aNav didMoveToParentViewController:aParent];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
  self.window.rootViewController = aParent;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;
}
@end

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
  { @autoreleasepool { return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate"); } }
```

The easiest way to reproduce the problem is:

1. Start the iOS Simulator.
2. Press ⌘+Y to turn on the in-call status bar. The status bar will become wide and green.
3. Launch the app manually and wait for the Navigation Controller to appear.
4. Press ⌘+Y again to turn off the in-call status bar.

The UI should now look as follows:
[image: Black gap instead of the status bar when switching the in-call status bar back off]

Anyone know how to fix the problem?

Comment: Did you try setting the size classes or auto resizing mask to `UINavigationContorller`'s view? because the resizing of the `UIWindow` of your app should work out of box. So I suspect the issue is with `UIView` of navigation controller.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue as described by the OP. Toggling the in-call status bar after the app has been launched results in expected behavior, but if the app is launched after the in-call status bar is on, then toggling off the in-call status bar will result in the black bar.

Comment: I also just tried it on an iOS device and the problem reproduces again, so it does not seem to be specific to the simulator.

Comment: @akivajgordon: no, it's absolutely not specific to the simulator. I mentioned the simulator simply because it is the easiest way to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Very well asked question. I was _easily_ able to reproduce the phenomenon, using your instructions. If only everyone would ask questions this way!

Comment: Rather than bashing your head against a wall, just start using AutoLayout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are adding a view (the navigation controller's view) as subview to another view (the parent view controller's view), without giving it a frame! This is something you should *never* do.

Just add these lines to your code:

```
aNav.view.frame = aParent.view.bounds;
aNav.view.autoresizingMask = 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Now the navigation controller's view has a frame, and maintains it in relation to its superview.

Comment: The second line is not totally necessary just to solve the problem you posed, but clearly you need not only a size but also a rule for what to do if the superview is resized. In real life I would probably use constraints rather than the `autoresizingMask`, but I wanted to keep it short.

Comment: And see my book for full details of the dance you must do when you do a custom parent view controller and add a child and its view: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers You are doing the steps in the wrong order (though I doubt whether that affects this particular issue).

Comment: Thanks buddy! You made my day! As brilliant as it is simple!

Comment: You get a lot of the credit. As I said before, you prepared the _question_ extremely well. You pared it down to the minimal case needed to reproduce the problem, and you provided code and instructions for reproducing the problem. I wish everyone would ask questions that way!

Comment: Was looking for this answer all day! Thanks so much!